# "I bleed silver and ocean lime."

Tags: meaning

> Yeah! Nobody loves the 'Zooks more than Klaus!
>
> ***I bleed silver and ocean lime.***
>
> Klaus, you're not coming

Hi,

not a native english languager here.

Could anyone please tell me, what does the line in bold text mean?

Cant find any info on it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [grammar correction: Could anyone tell me what the line in bold **means**?]

Comment: @Lambie - wouldn't just a colon do - Could anyone please tell me: What does the line in bold text mean?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Mine is simpler and also correct. But hey, be my guest.

Answer (score 3):

**You should have said where you saw  this text.**

Silver and ocean lime (a shade of green) are the colours of a fictional American football team, the Langley Falls Bazooka Sharks. Langley Falls is the fictional location of the TV series, 'American Dad', from which this dialogue comes.

We can say figuratively, if someone is very enthusiastic about, or committed to something (like a team, a nation, a company, a political party, etc), that, instead of red blood, they 'bleed' the colour or colours widely associated with that thing. These could be the colours worn by a team, or of a logo or flag.

Comment: You outdo yourself. Ha ha

Comment: @Lambie - 30 seconds approx on Google.

Comment: At Texas A&M, we "bleed maroon", but since that's a dark shade of red, it's a bit more literally accurate than the Bazooka Sharks.